# Biblatex errors, file not being recognized?

Tags: biblatex, errors

I am trying to use `biblatex` for the first time and running into problems. I looked up a lot of documentation, and here is what I have come up with so far.
Here is my report document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,float,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{spec.bib}
\begin{document}

random text let's cite \cite{spec}
\printbibliography
```

and here is my bibliography document `spec.bib`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{spec.bib}


@manual{spec,

    title =        {Instruction Manual and Experimental Guide for the PASCO Scientific Model SP-9268A, Student Spectrometer}. ,
    date =      {January 1991},
    OPTlanguage = {English},
    OPTorganization = {PASCO Scientific}
    OPTpagetotal = {10}}
```

When I try to cite this in my document, I am getting the following error and no output for my references:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
The top-level auxiliary file: Spectroscopy.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Spectroscopy.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Spectroscopy.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Spectroscopy.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Not too what to do to fix this. Any advice will be helpful, thank you!

Comment: You are running BIbTeX, but with your set-up you need to run Biber. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help on how to make your editor run Biber instead of BibTeX for you. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for background info on what Biber and BibTeX do.

Comment: Please note that `date =      {January 1991},` is incorrect. `date`-like fields must be filled in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (EDTF), so you'd have to write `date = {1991-01},`. You also have a spurious `.` after the `title = {...}` before the comma. It should be `title =  {Instruction Manual and Experimental Guide for the PASCO Scientific Model SP-9268A, Student Spectrometer},`

Comment: So according to the link about biber, the only thing I saw I needed to add was the [backend=biber]? Getting the same error.

Comment: No, that is definitely not the only thing you need to do (and in fact `backend=biber` is not necessary since it is the default, but I still like to include it nonetheless). If you use an editor, read up in [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) what to do - it depends on your editor. If you compile manually, don't call `bibtex <filename>`, but `biber <filename>`.

Comment: The file `spec.bib` should not have `\begin{filecontents}{spec.bib}`. This is only to store the references in the main `.tex` and sould hava a end (is not here). Consider use a program as JabRef. This help to  make a .bib file without syntactic errors (among many others advantages).

Answer (score 2):

As a quick workaround (but that is only to get you started!) you can add the option `backend=bibtex` to package `biblatex`.  Then BibTeX is used to create the bibliography ...

Now you can correct your errors in the code. In the bib file you have a `.` after the title you should delete and some missing commas. I corrected that in the following MWE.

I commented the packages not needed for your bibliography problem and added the missing `\end{document}`. The resulting code is `mwe.tex`, containing your bib file with package `filecontents`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{spec,
  title = {Instruction Manual and Experimental Guide for the PASCO 
           Scientific Model SP-9268A, Student Spectrometer},
  date  = {1991-01},
  OPTlanguage     = {English},
  OPTorganization = {PASCO Scientific},
  OPTpagetotal    = {10},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{graphicx,color,float,amssymb,amsmath}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage[font=small]{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[%
  style=numeric,
  backend=biber % biber bibtex <========================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % <===== to use the bib file created by filecontents

\begin{document}
random text let's cite \cite{spec}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

That will give you the result

[image]

after compiling with the chain

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
biber mwe       or: bibtex mwe
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

Change `backend=biber` to `backend=bibtex` to advice `biblatex` to use the backend you want to use.

Please follow the links given by user @moeve to learn how to configure your used editor to use `biber` instead of `bibtex` (recommended!).